# Duplicate a site in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I would like to duplicate an existing site in the present instance of Sharepoint 2010.
Can that be done by sharepoint designer ?

Are there any scripts that i can refer to in order to make the required changes ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use powershell export the site from source and import it to the new site location.

Good little script is located here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4890.how-to-exportimport-a-site-using-a-powershell-script-in-sharepoint-2007-and-sharepoint-2010-en-us.aspx